# Restrict search to specific channels

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I need search results for any query only from 450 channels of YouTube.

Can this work ? How can I build on this and assign the channels ? Please help.

```
<head>
    <title>YT-search only from specific channels</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
```

## search only form specific channels of YouTube

```
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function go_get() {
                var base_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=';
                var search_field = document.getElementById('yourtextfield').value;
                var target_url = base_url + search_field;
                var ifr = document.getElementById('youriframe');
                ifr.src = target_url;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <form onsubmit="go_get(); return false;">
            <input type="text" id="yourtextfield" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search Playlists" />
        </form>
        <iframe id="youriframe" width="640" height="360"></iframe>
    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes , you can do this .. Check this link it will be helpful to you

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#youtube_channels

or if you are using api response Then  check out this one

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list